# Does Rust box the individual items that are added to a vector?

Tags: vector, rust, heap-memory

According to the Rust documentation:

> Vectors always allocate their data on the heap.

As I understand this, it means that:

- Rust will allocate enough memory on the heap to store the type `T` in a contiguous fashion.
- Rust **will not** individually box the items as they are placed into the vector.

In other words, if I add a few integers to a vector, while the `Vec` will allocate enough storage to store those integers, it's not also going to box those integers; introducing another layer of indirection.

I'm not sure how I can illustrate or confirm this with code examples but any help is appreciated.

Comment: No. Correct. Correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, `Vec<T>` will store all items in a contiguous buffer rather than boxing them individually. [The documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) states:

> A *contiguous* growable array type, written `Vec<T>` but pronounced 'vector.'

Note that it is also possible to slice a vector, to get a `&[T]` (slice). [Its documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html), again, confirms this:

> A dynamically-sized view into a *contiguous* sequence, `[T]`.
>
> Slices are a view into a *block of memory* represented as a pointer and a length.