# If I make a struct and put it in a vector, does it reside on the heap or the stack?

Tags: struct, rust, heap-memory

I'm writing some code that generates a vector of geometric elements:

```
struct Geom_Entity {
    // a bunch of geometric information,
    // like tangent planes, force vectors, etc
}
```

The code is parsing many of these entities from a text file (for e.g.) so we have a function currently:

```
parse_Geom(x: String) -> Vec<Geom_Entity> { 
    // a bunch of code
}
```

These geometric entities are large structs with 17 `f64`s and a few other fields.  The file may contain well over 1000 of these, but not so many that they can't all fit into memory (at least for now).

Also, should I be doing

```
Box::new(Geom_Entity { ...
```

and then putting the box in the vector?

Comment: Idiomatic Rust code uses `PascalCase` (no underscores) for type names (`GeomEntity`) and `snake_case` for variables and function names (`parse_geom`).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [documentation for `Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) says (emphasis mine):

> If a `Vec` has allocated memory, then **the memory it points to is on the heap**

So yes, the members of the vector are owned by the vector and are stored on the heap.

---

In *general*, boxing an element before putting it in the `Vec` is wasteful - there's extra memory allocation and indirection. There are times when you need that extra allocation or indirection, so it's never say never.

See also:

- [Does Rust box the individual items that are added to a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39679310/155423)

Comment: `Vec<Box<T>>` where `T` is a trait type is probably the most common case of the elements themselves being boxed.